# Can previous versions of ActiveMQ Artemis interact with the current version?

Tags: activemq-artemis

For example could a 2.1X (X < 9) client interact with a 2.19 server?

Comment: Just wanted to give some time incase anything else popped up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general older clients should work with newer brokers, although there may be new features in the broker which the older clients can't use properly.